# Saving entity in repository does not work SPRING

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data

I'm trying to save entity in repository but it does not work at all. Repository is Autowired and in runtime I use saveAndFlush to save entity. I'm using PostgreSQL. Above test methods I added comments with explanation what is going on. I expected that method saveAndFlush should work but it did not. I can not find why.

```
@Transactional
public class TestClass{

    @Autowired private MyRepository repository;
    @Autowired private EntityManager entityManager;

    // Working version
    public void writingToRepositoryWorking() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(new MyData(99));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    // not working and throws exception : 
    // TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    public void writingToRepositoryNotWorking() {
        repository.saveAndFlush(new MyData(99));
    }

    // not working, no exception, no data in repository, 
    // but auto generated ID is incremented
    public void writingToRepositoryNotWorkingToo() {
        repository.save(new MyData(99));
    }
}
```

repository interface file

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyData, Long> {}
```

MyData file

```
@Entity(name = "myData")
public class MyData {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) long id;

    private int testValue;

    public MyData() { }

    public BugData(int testValue) {
        this.testValue = testValue;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getTestValue() {
        return testValue;
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfiguration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mypackage.app")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Value("${jdbc.url}") private String KEY_JDBC_URL;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}") private String KEY_JDBC_USERNAME;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}") private String KEY_JDBC_PASSWORD;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackage.app");
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(KEY_JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(KEY_JDBC_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(KEY_JDBC_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory  entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackage.app");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        em.afterPropertiesSet();

        return em.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong transaction manager. For JPA you need a `JpaTransactionManager` not the `HibernateTransactionManager`. Also why mix the 2.

Comment: Instead of creating 2 instances, just create a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` and use the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` to expose a `SessionFactory`. You now just need a single transactionamanger and can use both JPA and a plain Hibernate `SessionFactory` if you really need this.

Comment: It does not help, because I still have to beginTransaction and commit instead of using saveAndFlush on repository. Do you think it may be hibernate+postgresql specific case? Can it be done without calling begin and commit?

Comment: Transactional on an interface doesn't do much (and there have been changes in how Spring Data handles that). Annotate your testclass with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Testclass is Transactional I missed that when copying.

Comment: Then I doubt that you posted everything needed here... How are you testing, how are things loaded etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For starter, you're actually working on 2 different `EntityManager` in your non-working test case:

1. `EntityManager` autowired into your test by Spring (this one is singleton and should be avoided anyway) ,other is
2. `EntityManager` created by the `EntityManagerFactory` configured in your ApplicationConfiguration.

At the same time, you also have another Session running along side the aforementioned 2 `EntityManagers` due to your configuration of Hibernate `SessionFactory`. Additionally, because of the configured `HibernateTransactionManager`, all transactions created by `@Transactional` are bound to the Hibernate's Session created by `SessionFactory` and the `EntityManager` used by your Repository certainly has no way to know about it. This is why `TransactionRequiredException` was thrown when your Repository tried to persist data.

To fix it, *you may consider removing the Hibernate's `SessionFactory`* and switch the transaction manager to a `JpaTransactionManager`. Then, `@Transactional` on your Repository will have the effect of creating a new transaction and binding it to the existing `EntityManager` that is known to Spring.

One side note is that the `@Transactional` on your TestClass doesn't help at all as the instance of this class is not instantiated and managed by Spring. To make this work, a proper configuration of transactional test class needs to be provided as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have deleted all unnecessary things from application configuration and its working now! Thanks for response